# Error deploying QuickAction to Campaign

Tags: deployment, lookup, ant, quickaction

I have a QuickAction that I'm trying to deploy (using Ant) to a new Developer org. The quick action creates a new child Campaign and uses the ParentId field. Also, this quick action exists in other Developer orgs I use, which I'm assuming was created using the UI, so it's a valid QuickAction. At any rate, when trying to deploy, I get the following error:

> Error: Target object does not have a valid lookup or master-detail reference to the parent object

Uh, this is not true as Campaign obviously looks up to itself using ParentId. I also verified that my user profile has read/update permissions on ParentId. I've done other searches on the Internets to no avail. Does anybody have any ideas?

Let me know if you have any questions/need additional information.

Thank you much!

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I'm having the same issue...

Comment: @thegogz Posted the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The deploying user did not have `Marketing User` checked in the user's detail page. Therefore, the user didn't have access to Campaigns and could not deploy the create campaign quick action.